# jQuery multiple div drop downs menu

Tags: jquery, css

I have this almost working but I'm losing my mind on the jQuery (I'm not very good at it, but learning)

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5CRA5/4/

Because I can't show you the drop down from the dynamically created post query I created a search button below the operations and settings buttons that you can click that would have been in the div drop down.

Everything works great except that when or if someone had the settings menu down, and they then clicked on operations. It would just pull the menu away, and not place the new one.  I thought I had the code right but its not working that way. I have to be missing something. All the other menus are working great in that it pulls them away, and places the right one.

Also, is there a way to make it that the post doesn't happen until the div is fully up? So that when you bring it back down it seems seamless. I found that the way it is now. You can sometimes see it replace the info before its up.

Below is the jQuery code for those that can just look at it and see what I'm doing wrong.

```
        function menuCall(div_id, bottom, filename) {
            $('[id^="menu_"]').animate({"top": "-50px"}, "slow");
            $('[id^="menu_"]').delay(500).queue( function(next){$(this).hide();next();});

            $.post("/opserv/" + filename, function(ajaxresult){
                $('#'+div_id).html(ajaxresult);
            });

            if ($('#'+div_id).css('top') !== bottom + 'px') {
                $('#'+div_id).queue( function(next){$(this).show();next();});
                $('#'+div_id).animate({"top": "+" + bottom + "px"}, "slow");
            } else {
                $('#'+div_id).animate({"top": "-50px"}, "slow");
                $('#'+div_id).delay(500).queue( function(next){$(this).hide();next();});
            }
        }
```

Comment: Im sure there is something simple to making it work. I just havent figured it out yet. I'll figure it out eventually. I just figured after an hour of playing with it and still not getting it.. I'd ask here.

Comment: Banana Yours still doesn't work. Clicking Settings, and then Clicking Operation does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is happening because you are referring to the same div - Both Operations and Settings buttons are pointing to menu_panel-2 , which causes the div to toggle as it acts as you press Settings twice or Operations twice (to show and hide the menu). So you have to find a way first to tell the function which button is pressed - whether it is Settings or Operations. I made it by simply adding a new variable to the function - > "type" . Then you have to check if the type is 'Ops' for operations or 'Set' for 'settings'. Then if it is one of them you simple showing the div. Note that this will not let you to hide the Operations or Settings menu once opened, the only way to hide it is if you switch to search and then click search again. So you have to check which is the last button pressed by simply adding a variable to save it for you, then you compare it with the 'type'.

http://jsfiddle.net/5CRA5/12/

```
   var check = ''
function menuCall(div_id, bottom, filename,type) {
    $('[id^="menu_"]').animate({"top": "-50px"}, "slow");
    $('[id^="menu_"]').delay(500).queue( function(next){$(this).hide();next();});

    $.post("/opserv/" + filename, function(ajaxresult){
        $('#'+div_id).html(ajaxresult);
    });

    if ($('#'+div_id).css('top') != bottom + 'px') {
        $('#'+div_id).queue( function(next){$(this).show();next();});
        $('#'+div_id).animate({"top": "+" + bottom + "px"}, "slow");
    } else {
        if(type=='Ops' || type =='Set'){
            if (check == type){
               $('#'+div_id).animate({"top": "-50px"}, "slow");
            $('#'+div_id).delay(500).queue( function(next){$(this).hide();next();}); 
            }
            else{
            $('#'+div_id).queue( function(next){$(this).show();next();});
            $('#'+div_id).animate({"top": "+" + bottom + "px"}, "slow");
            } 
        }
        else{
        $('#'+div_id).animate({"top": "-50px"}, "slow");
        $('#'+div_id).delay(500).queue( function(next){$(this).hide();next();});
        }

    }
    check = type;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad to hear that, keep in mind that this code is not optimized. You can do this by simply make two functions -> for hiding and for showing which you will call in different scenarios. That way it will be more readable.

Comment: I have about 6 menus I have to do like this and yours made it more adverse. While it may not be very easy to read. I can understand it very well. Just wondering if there is a way to delay the post still though. Like make it do the post once the div his the top. I'm sure there is a completed check.. just trying to figure out where to put that.

Comment: I am not sure what you meant here, currently(as per my point of view) if the menu is shown, once it should be switched it disappears completely before the next one is about to pop up. You want to skip this delay and to make the div starts showing when at the same time it starts hiding or you want to hide it, wait 2 sec for example and show the next one ?

Comment: Yeah I figured it out. I added a delay. As when you do it. When I wanted was for when the menu was pulled up. It would re-write the dive, and then pull the menu down so it looked seemless. The way it worked there it would draw the screen once the div finished moving up.